# sed replace spaces in directory names

Tags: bash, macos, sed

I'm trying to replace `space` with `-` in *directory* names, not *file* names on macOS. I have the following:

```
cd ~/foo
for directory in **; do
    if [[ -d $directory ]] && [[ -w $directory ]]; then
        sed -i '' 's/  /-/g' "$directory"
    fi
done
```

However I'm getting an error `in-place editing only works for regular files`.

How can I replace spaces in directory names?

Comment: To be clear: do you want to *rename* your directories, or just print a list of modified directory names?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sed` is meant for search and replacement on files and *not* on directories in  Linux/Unix. The `-i` flag in `sed` is used to make the text replacement on-the-fly on a file, the action simply does not make sense for a directory. You probably meant to change the name of the directory using `sed` on the filename and eventually use `mv` to rename the actual directory with the replaced string.

But you could just use `mv` in the first place with shell native features to replace white space with a `-` character.

```
for directory in **; do
    if [[ -d $directory ]] && [[ -w $directory ]]; then
        mv -- "$directory" "${directory// /-}"
    fi
done
```

Comment: Nice! This is what I was originally looking for when `sed` was recommended

Answer (score 0):

To rename directory, you must use command `mv`

```
#!/bin/bash

cd foo
for directory in **; do
    if [[ -d $directory ]] && [[ -w $directory ]]; then
        newdir=`echo "$directory" |sed  's/ /-/g' `
        if [ "$directory" -ne "$newdir" ]
           mv -- "$directory" "$newdir"
        fi
    fi
done
```

Comment: Watch out for directories starting with `-` for example. You might want to add `mv -- "$directory"...`.

Comment: You are right, write a collect shell script is hard

Answer (score -1):

```
directory=`echo $directory | sed 's/ /-/g'`
```

Comment: You're right about the spaces, edited my answer. OP did ask about how to "to replace space with - in directory names", not "rename" the directories.

Answer (score -1):

`sed` is versatile but I suggest you use a more specialised tool such as `rename`:

```
rename 's/ /-/g' "$directory"
```

Also you're very likely to try and rename already renamed directories (and thus no longer existing). I suggest you use `find` options `-depth` (depth first) and `-execdir` (execute command inside directory, to avoid affecting parent directories):

```
find foo -depth -type d -execdir rename 's/ /-/g' {} +
```